# Divisão resultando sempre em zero

Tags: java, matemática, tipagem

O resultado de Alfa só está retornando 0. Por que?

```
package javaapplication4;

public class MediaMovelSuavizaçãoExp {


    public double CalculoPrevisao(double[] valores){

        double[] values = new double[valores.length];

        //Calculando o valor de alfa

        double alfa = 2 / ( values.length + 1);

        return alfa;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está fazendo uma divisão de inteiros, então o resultado é inteiro, mesmo que depois guarde em um `double`. Então divida um `double`, assim:

```
return 2.0 / (values.length + 1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mVGKhL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hbttjwwt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Division.java).

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.